# Left Hand Side Conditional Assignment

Tags: javascript

Is this possible in javascript?

```
let a, b; // Both objects, eg vectors
let bl = false; // This is a bool that could be true or false

// Is this possible, or how could it be done
(bl ? a : b) = {x: 5, y: -2, z: 3};
```

Ie, I want to set either `a` or `b` to this vector conditionally depending on `bl`.

Or is the only way:

```
let tmp = {x: 5, y: -2, z: 3};
if(bl) a = tmp;
else b = tmp;
```

I just feel there should be a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: don't sacrifice code readability for "elegance"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in a way it is but it's just a short hand of what you wrote as an alternative.

```js
let a, b;
let bl = true;

let obj = {x: 5, y: -2, z: 3}

bl ? a = obj : b = obj;
```

Comment: I would recommend against doing this in general, since it's significantly less readable. But if you do, at least use parens: `bl ? (a = obj) : (b = obj);`

Answer (score 3):

While not architecturally the same, you could achieve the same logic by simply using an object to hold the vars:

```js
let vectors = {a:{}, b:{}}; // Both objects, eg vectors
let bl = false; // This is a bool that could be true or false

vectors[(bl ? 'a' : 'b')] = {x: 5, y: -2, z: 3};
```

Alternatively (and maybe faster), an array could by used with indices in place of the names 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 2):

Decidedly not elegant or something you should use, but it *is* possible to slide an array around to get that effect:

```
[a, b] = [a, {x: 5, y: -2, z: 3}, b].slice(bl);
```